# Bootstrap-vue still recommended with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Since Bootstrap 5 no longer using jQuery and is using vanilla JS I'm wondering if Bootstrap-Vue is still recommended being used or not, regardless of the fact that Bootstrap-Vue don't support Bootstrap 5 yet.

Just wanna get an idea if I should start learning Bootstrap-Vue or not.

Answer (score 17):

BootstrapVue is currently an implementation of Bootstrap 4.5 on Vue 2.6.

It's not using Vue 3.

It's not using Bootstrap 5.

Discussion around a Vue 3 + Bootstrap 4 version [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196).
Authors also mention work on a Bootstrap 5 + Vue 3 has not started yet but it's planned, on a separate branch.

---

Should you learn this version of BootstrapVue?
The concepts won't change much, but the implementation might, (not so much around template syntax, but more on controller syntax - around object vs composition API usage).

On the other hand, one could argue if you know Vue 2 object API syntax and have reasonable knowledge of Bootstrap 4, there's hardly anything to learn about BootstrapVue.

Currently, if a company wants to use BootstrapVue in production, they'll use Vue 2.6.12 and Bootstrap v4.5.3, even if they plan on refactoring for Vue 3 + Bootstrap 5 at some later point, when they become production ready.

The vast majority of companies using Vue right now are using Vue 2 and, because no major UI library (BootstrapVue, Vuetify) has released a Vue 3 version, the only option for using Vue 3 is writing your own CSS/theme, which most don't deem worth investing in.

---

Getting back to your question, it roughly translates into: should I learn Vue 2 and Bootstrap 4? My personal answer is: *"Definitely."* They will be in usage for many years to come, even after a BootstrapVue version for Vue 3 + Bootstrap 5 will be out.

Also, there's a high probability having knowledge about how current version works will give you a significant advantage in learning and understanding future versions.

---

Minor note: you start your question by saying

> *"Since Bootstrap 5 no longer using jQuery..."*

BootstrapVue means ***Bootstrap powered by Vue instead of jQuery***. BootstrapVue has always been jQuery-less. That's the main reason why people use it: to get Bootstrap in Vue projects without jQuery dependency.

Comment: I like your answer @tao, but can you go a bit more in detail to the question? Because I ask my self the same: when bootstrap 5 don't need jquery anymore, and jquery less is one of the main reasons to use bootstrapVue -> why still stick on bootstrapVue, when bootstrap 5 don't need jquery anymore? Why not just using bootstrap 5 in vue, without any overhead of another framework?

Comment: @jb, take a look at BootstrapVue's table component.

Comment: @jb_alvarado Bootstrap has a very extensive and well crafted CSS, of which jQuery + jQueryUI is compatible with. If you planned to use Bootstrap 5 together with a vue library, e.g. vuetify or Quasar then you will likely experience incompatibilities in the CSS. Functionally everything works fine, but the styling will be off.